# c program Bubble Sort for strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting, pointers

I am writing a program that takes an array of pointers to strings and I am writing a function to put them in order. I think I have the ground work of bubble sort, but all the items in the list are just switching one position instead of being sorted.

Here is main

```
char *bubble[5] = { "cats", "dogs", "bananas", "apples", "sugar" };
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%s ", bubble[i]);
}
printf("\n");
bubble_sort(bubble, 5);
i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%s ", bubble[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

and here is my function

```
void bubble_sort(int *list[], int size)
/*
This sorts a list of strings
*/
{
    int u = 0, c = 0, passes = 0;
    char *temp = '/0';
    u = size - 1;

    while (u > 0)
    {
        c = 1;
        while (c < u)
        {
            if (strcmp(list[c], list[c - 1]))
            {
                temp = list[c];
                list[c] = list[c-1];
                list[c - 1] = temp;
                c++;
            }
            u--;
        }
    }

}
```

I guess my problem is getting the pointers to change the contents of the bubble array so that I can print in main

Comment: `list[c] != list[u]` and `list[c] < list[c - 1]` - that isn't how you compare null-terminated strings in C. Use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp). One of the *many* duplicates of this problem [can be found **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587574/compare-with-string-in-if-statement-doesnt-work).

Comment: You use `strcmp`(in `#include <string.h>`) to compare strings

Comment: return value of `strcmp(A, B)` | 0 mean A == B, > 0 mean A > B, < 0 mean A < B. See [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: Also `while (list[c] not equal list[u])` and position of `u--;` are probably  mistakes

Comment: `int *list[]` --> `char *list[]`

Comment: position of `c++` is also wrong. fix like [this](http://ideone.com/sRhf7o)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks! all fixed :D